# Defining a Style with a DataTrigger in ResourceDictionary but specify the DataTrigger binding path in the view

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, resourcedictionary

I want to define a general look and feel of a control in a `ResourceDictionary` using a style with a `DataTrigger`.

Is it possible to specify the `DataTrigger` binding path in the view?
If not, is there some neat alternative to reach my goal?

My goal is to reuse the graphical definition (including triggers) but link the trigger to a different data source each time I use it.

Example style:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="LedBehavior">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightGray"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding **DefineThisPathInTheView**}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="DarkGreen"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

In the view I hope to use this style somewhat like this:

```
<Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" 
           Style="{StaticResource LedBehavior}"
           DataTriggerBindingPath="**PropertyInViewModel**"/>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't believe you can. I think when you bind your property in DataTrigger, it will try and find that property in your data context.

Comment: Thanx! Your tip helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution appears very neat and not too difficult.

I have to bind the `DataContext` of (in this case) my `Rectangle` to the property I want. Then I have to bind the trigger in my style to the `DataContext`.

The working example below.

Example style:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="LedBehavior">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="LightGray"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="DarkGreen"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Example (part of) view:

```
<Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" 
           Style="{StaticResource LedBehavior}"
           DataContext="{Binding PropertyInViewModel}"/>
```

I hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the DataContext you maybe can use attached properties and bind to this.